# Java how to configure log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

i want to use log4j2 in my java web application.

This is my dependency tree printed by maven

```
[INFO] com.mypackage.app:APP:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-servlet:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-autotag-core-runtime:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-jsp:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.17.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:20030825.184428:compile
[INFO] +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:20030825.183949:compile
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:20040616:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:20030203.000129:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:20030211.134440:compile
[INFO] +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.22:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.0-beta5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.0-beta5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun:jconsole:jar:1.6.0:system
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time-hibernate:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Beta2:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.4:compile
[INFO]    \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
```

I'm a little confused about log library used by libs included in my application so i had to include commons.logging, slf4 and apache log4j version 2.0-beta5.

I've created log4j2.xml file and putted it in classpath, this is my log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="debug" packages="com.mypackage.app">
  <appenders>
    <File name="APPENDER_FILE" fileName="logs/app.log" append="false">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p [%C:%L] - %m%n"/>
    </File>
    <Console name="APPENDER_OUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p [%C:%L] - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
    <root level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="APPENDER_OUT"/>
      <appender-ref ref="APPENDER_FILE"/>
    </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

When application starts in tomcat7 follow messages appears in eclipse console

```
mag 03, 2013 2:46:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing log4j from [classpath:log4j2.xml]
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 65
log4j:WARN L'elemento radice "configuration" del documento deve corrispondere alla radice DOCTYPE "null".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 65
log4j:WARN Documento non valido: nessuna grammatica trovata.
log4j:WARN The <configuration> element has been deprecated.
log4j:WARN Use the <log4j:configuration> element instead.
log4j:WARN Unrecognized element appenders
log4j:WARN Unrecognized element loggers
mag 03, 2013 2:46:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I think that messages are refers to log4j configuration and not log4j2. Is it right?

How i can configure it to use only log4j2 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the `slf4j-log4j` bridge JAR file with the `slf4j-log4j2` bridge JAR.  You can read about it here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/

Once you've done that the log4j dependency should disappear too ... unless something else is using it directly.

To understand what is going on, refer to the documentation for slf4j.

---

FWIW, the parse errors look like they are due to log4j trying (and failing) to parse a log4j2 format configuration file.  (That ain't going to work, though I doubt that you are intending that to happen.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but probably the following line indicates that log4j is getting added to your classpath and must be causing log4j to execute instead of log4j2:

```
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile

[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
```

As suggested by the migration guide I think you should remove all log4j dependencies from the classpath first.
Try excluding the log4j dependency from the above jar.

Hope this helps.